# HTML: How to design profile page that is used for different users

Tags: html, web-services, profile, servlet-3.0

I want to make a website for my Android social networking app and need some assistance with a basic concept regarding user profile pages. So right now I have a native Android app where users have their own profile page displaying their profile stats, e.g. followers etc. and I would like to do something similar in HTML. My question is how can I design a generic profile.html page that displays the current user's username/stats and that can be used for different users? For example, see how Facebook are using the same profile page for each user but they replace the name/bio/stats fields with the data for the current user, how is that done - at the server side (by replacing the appropriate fields with the data for the current user), or at the client side (by loading them with a separate script after the page has loaded)?

Also, I am using a Tomcat servlet to deal with the requests if anyone is interested.

Thanks for any assistance and sorry if the question is silly :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use PHP. Think of webpages as a mathmatical equation where HTML is 3+4=12 but PHP is 3+X=12. HTML is already defined, you can't change it. Where PHP you can code the entire page but get the bio or username from a database.

But you should be warned that this is no simple task, you would have to create a large mySQL database, possibly more to handle logging in and out and use the PHP to define what you are calling for form the mySQL database.

It is possible, but not in a day.